# I'm trying to count non integers in double arrays in Python

Tags: python, arrays, count, isalpha

I'd like to count the number of non integers in double array.
For example

```
Input: mylist=[['a',-2,'b',-3,1],['c','a',-1,1,3],['d','f'],['e',3],[-11]]
Output: num_value(mylist)=7
```

Show me how to make it.

Comment: Could you please show us your own attempt to get Python code to reach to a solution

Comment: I really don't see why this is downvoted so much. I've seen "wall of code" questions with 1 upvote...

Comment: I believe most voters like to see some effort on the questioners part.

Comment: the fact that the question is clear is more important than the effort.

Comment: check that one, makes me arrrrghhh (warning wall of code ahead): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42676242/python-functions-and-variables-trouble

Comment: another bad one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42676367/how-to-make-this-code-menu-operated-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Count instances of non-integers in the lists of lists (using double `for` in generator comprehension fed to `sum`)

```
mylist=[['a',-2,'b',-3,1],['c','a',-1,1,3],['d','f'],['e',3],[-11]]

print(sum(1 for sl in mylist for x in sl if not isinstance(x,int)))
```

yields: `7`

Comment: @Ev.Kounis so your code is correct :) and thx for the upvote (I would have done the same, since the question is really not that bad!)

Comment: Well that I knew. #laughsInArrogant

Comment: I though of making a function out of it as in the OPs example and that cost me. never again

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Thank you.