# Python functions and variables trouble

Tags: python, function

I have created this code so far...

```
def print_slow(str):
    for letter in str:
        sys.stdout.write(letter)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(0.005)

def menu():
    print_slow("-------------[MENU]-------------")
    print(" ")
    print_slow("1) Enter a sentence.")
    print(" ")
    print_slow("2) Find the position of  a word.")
    print(" ")
    print_slow("--------------------------------")
    print(" ")

    print_slow(">>> ")
    choice = str(input(" "))
    print(" ")
    time.sleep(0.5)

    if choice == "1":
        option1()
    if choice == "2":
        option2()

def option1():
    print_slow("Enter sentence")
    sentence = str(input(": "))
    print(" ")
    menu()

def option2():
    if not sentence:
        print_slow("Please enter a sentence first!")
        time.sleep(0.5)
        print(" ")

    else:
        sentenceUppercase = sentence.upper()
        [code goes on...]
```

Basically when I test it, I press option 2 first and it should give the output 'Please enter a sentence first!', which it does.

I then press option 1 in the menu and it should prompt me to input a sentence (I put 'my name is bob' as a test) and it does.

**I then pressed option 2 after inputting the sentence and it *should* continue with my code - instead it gives the error message 'Please enter a sentence first!'**

How can I fix this??

Comment: Why do you need time.sleeps?

Comment: It's part of my code but that's not really relevant @nbro

Comment: Have you defined `sentence` as a global variable? Because the code you're showing us should give an error because in the function `option2` you're checking if `sentence` evaluates to True (or False), but, from your code, that `sentence` seems not to be defined anywhere. In other words, `sentence` under `option1` is a local variable and not the same variable as in `option2`.

Comment: You have a scope issue with your variable sentence.

Comment: I've done `sentence = " "` right at the start of my code at the first line but the error still comes up @nbro

Comment: initialize sentence inside main, and then put option1 and option2 inside menu

Comment: Additionally, calling `option1()` from `menu()` and `menu()` from `option1()` is not the way to go. Those are function calls, which will return to that point in the code after the function is finished and `return`s something. Those are not jumps in the code, you are cluttering your memory with lots of "instances" of your functions, that are waiting for returns of other functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're setting a *local* variable `sentence` inside function `option1`. This variable is not visible in `option2` since it lives inside `option1` only and will be cleaned up once `option1` is finished.

If you want to share the variable, you need to define it as `global` at least in `option1`:

```
def option1():
    print_slow("Enter sentence")
    global sentence
    sentence = str(input(": "))
    print(" ")
    menu()
```

Note, however, that using global variables is usually a sign of bad code quality. In your case, it would make more sense to have `option1` return `sentence` to `main`, and pass it from `main` to `option2`.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is in assigning a value to `sentence`.  Since you are assigning it in a function, when you leave that function's scope, you lose the value.  Try using `global`:

```
sentence = ''

def option1():
    global sentence              # <-- this maintains its value in global scope
    print_slow("Enter sentence")
    sentence = str(input(": "))
    print(" ")
    menu()

def option2():
    global sentence              # <-- and here
    if not sentence:
        print_slow("Please enter a sentence first!")
        time.sleep(0.5)
        print(" ")
    else:
        sentenceUppercase = sentence.upper()
```

Or you could pass it back and forth with parameters.